# Django with DEBUG = True and django.contrib.staticfiles not finding static files

Tags: python, django

I am running Django with DEBUG = True and staticfiles in the INSTALLED_APPS. However my program is not finding the static files. I don't really want to do collectstatic... Is there any common reason why this may happen?

Comment: Can you post your `settings.py` for static here.

Comment: It is not allowing me to add the complete settings.py... However DEBUG = True and INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
]

Comment: Update your question with your `settings.py`.

Comment: It says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details" :/

Comment: Add `static` only part of your `settings.py`.

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('static'), )